# WP_Query not using custom taxonomy categories on custom post type

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, advanced-custom-fields, advanced-taxonomy-queries

So I have both a custom post type which is called 'Recipes' in my register method() as shown below:

```
public static function register()
{
    add_action('init', function() {
        $labels = array(
            'name' => __('Recipes'),
            'singular_name' => __('Recipe'),
            'nickname' => __('Recipe'),
            'add_new' => _x('Add Recipe', 'Recipe'),
            'edit_item' => __('Edit Recipe'),
        );
        $args = array(
            'labels' => $labels,
            'slug' => 'recipe',
            'plural' => 'Recipes',
            'public' => true, // Adds the 'View' option.
            'show_ui' => true,
            'show_in_admin_bar' => true,
            'show_in_rest' => true, // Show the new Gutenberg editor
            'supports' => array('title', 'editor', 'thumbnail'),
            'taxonomies' => array('recipe_categories'),
        );
        register_post_type('recipe', $args);

        $labels = array(
            'name'              => _x( 'Categories', 'taxonomy general name', 'textdomain' ),
            'singular_name'     => _x( 'Category', 'taxonomy singular name', 'textdomain' ),
            'search_items'      => __( 'Search Categories', 'textdomain' ),
            'all_items'         => __( 'All Categories', 'textdomain' ),
            'parent_item'       => __( 'Parent Category', 'textdomain' ),
            'parent_item_colon' => __( 'Parent Category:', 'textdomain' ),
            'edit_item'         => __( 'Edit Category', 'textdomain' ),
            'update_item'       => __( 'Update Category', 'textdomain' ),
            'add_new_item'      => __( 'Add New Category', 'textdomain' ),
            'new_item_name'     => __( 'New Category Name', 'textdomain' ),
            'menu_name'         => __( 'Categories', 'textdomain' ),
        );

        $args = array(
            'hierarchical'      => true,
            'labels'            => $labels,
            'show_ui'           => true,
            'show_admin_column' => true,
            'query_var'         => true,
            'rewrite'           => array('slug' => 'recipe_categories'),
        );
        register_taxonomy('recipe_categories', array('recipe'), $args);
    });
```

This created both my custom post type and my custom taxonomy - I've assigned the custom category to one of my posts:
[image]

It's showing in the database under `wp_term_taxonomy` that it's being used as the count has risen:
[image]

Inside the `wp_posts` table, under my single post it doesn't have any indication of categories (Unsure if it's supposed to be like this)
[image]

Then I have a get() method that retrieves the meta using WP_Query:

```
public static function get()
{
    $recipes = [];

    $terms = get_terms('recipe_categories');

    $args = [
        'post_type' => 'recipe',
        'post_status' => 'publish',
        'orderby' => 'title',
        'order' => 'ASC',
        'posts_per_page' => 10,
    ];

    $recipe_query = new WP_Query($args);

    var_dump($recipe_query);

    foreach ($recipe_query->posts as $post) {
        $recipes[] = Recipe::init($post->ID);
    }

    return $recipes;
}
```

I get the object with posts but nothing that is linking to an 'taxonomies' as shown below:

[image]

Does anyone know what I might be missing?

Answer (score 0):

`WP_Query` only returns `WP_Post` objects for the results. To get the taxonomy terms for each post you need to use `get_the_terms( $post, 'recipe_categories' );` for each post.

This is because `WP_Post` represents each row of `wp_posts`, which does not include taxonomy information. The links between posts and terms is in the `wp_term_relationships` table.